# Error while fetching the array

Tags: php

I have the following code which is generating error while fetching the elements of the array

```
 $task = new task();
    $task->connect();
    $services = $task->viewTask_front_android($_GET['pno']); 
    print_r($services);
     while($info =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($services)) 
     { 
     Print "<b>Name:</b> ".$info['starttime'] . " "; 

     } ?>
```

from the print_r(services) iam getting

```
Array ( [task_id] => 14 [user_id] => 123 [employee_id] => 456 [service_id] => 2 [starttime] => 2:00 AM [endtime] => 4:00 AM [servicename] => se a [servicedescription] => ddsdsd [employeename] => dsd [employeepicture] => pictures/noimage.gif [pic_path] => pictures/noimage.gif )
```

is there any problem with 
     while($info =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($services)) 
it is generating error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\proj\android\services.php on line 70`

Comment: there is no problem with that.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Whatever `$services` is, it is *not a valid MySQL result resource*. **Edit**: It is already the result array (as you can see at the output), so no need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Just iterate normally over the array.

Comment: @umar: It is a valid array, but not a valid MySQL result resource. That is something different.

Comment: Thanks for your concern now its giving Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:\wamp\www\proj\android\services.php on line 70

Comment: @umar: I already said, use a normal `for` or `foreach` loop to iterate over the array. `viewTask_front_android` already gave you the result. There are no DB functions involved anymore.

Comment: @Felix Kling  thank you , let me give a try to it

Comment: Btw. you might want to [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) (especially the return value part) to learn what a MySQL result research actually is. This will help you understand that it is not an array.

Comment: @umar: And actually in this case, if you just want to output the `'starttime'` value, you don't have to iterate over the array. See @Ribose's answer.

Comment: @ Felix Kling Thanks  a lot i will give a read to what you have recommended

Comment: This implies an SQL syntax error. There is nothing reproducible to go on here, so **close vote** from me.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, the problem was that `$services` was already an array.

Comment: @Felix: Well, that's a shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

```
$services = $task->viewTask_front_android($_GET['pno']);
```

is already returning an array (a single row, from appearance). You don't/can't fetch an array from it as if it were the result of `mysql_query`, because it's not.

Instead, just print `$services['starttime']`:

```
print "<b>Name:</b> ".$services['starttime'] . " ";
```

Edit: If I was unclear, remove the while loop completely as well.

Answer (score 1):

No need for loop, it returns one dimensional array...

```
Print "<b>Name:</b> $services[starttime] ";
```